# Firebase Swift Naming Children - Nth Name / Duplicate Childs?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was wondering whether it is possible to have multiple children under the same name. The reason I ask is that if a user on my app chooses to add the same item it replaces the values under the child as the child name is the item name. Is there a way I can have multiple childs of same item name? Or would there be a way to name the children such as 'Item' ... 'Item +1'.  Thanks !

Example Firebase Structure

```
users
 -> user id
   -> milk
     -> weight : 2
   -> milk // instead of updating the previous child i would want to add another child of same name
     -> weight : 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot have duplicate keys in Firebase Realtime Database as it stores the data in a giant JSON like structure and JSON cannot have duplicate keys. Even if you try adding them manually from the console itself, the last value is going to overwrite the previous ones.

You should restructure your database a bit. Try adding item IDs to each item as shown below:
[image]

You can use `.childByAutoId()` method which generated the randomKey for you:

```
ref.child("order1/items/").childByAutoId().key
```

You can find more about [childByAutoId](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#update_specific_fields)
If you want your nodes to be numbered like milk1, milk2 and so on, then you would have to store the count of milk nodes in a separate location in the database and read that value before adding any new milk item. Make sure you increment that value each time you add the item.

However, that just sounds a long process of reading and writing and incrementing. I'd recommend to use the random keys as explained above. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: That makes so much sense! Thank you for replying to this. I'll have to look into restructuring my database. Thanks again